# Certificate Renewal using Powershell - Remotely downloading a user's certificate

Tags: powershell

I am writing a Powershell script for renewing user certificates.
I am trying to automate a step in which

- I log in to a server using the account's credentials,
- Go to mmc,
- Right click on the certificate and then renew it.

I have been successful in writing the script for renewal But I am stuck at the login part.

Accessing the server remotely using Enter-PSSession and Invoke-Command doesn't install the user's certificate the way it does in case of a manual login.

Is there any powershell command or any work around that can be used to fetch a user's certificate just like it happens automatically in case of a manual login?

Comment: if you login to the server and run the powershell command that you're wrapping in your scriptblock for `Invoke-Command`, does it behave the same as it does remotely? If so, what's different about using Powershell vs using MMC? If it works via Powershell directly from the server itself, then I suspect it's a double hop issue. If running it in Powershell directly on the server yields the same behavior as remote, then you're likely targeting the wrong certificate store. Needs more details on what the differences are and how it behaves when you rule out running the command remotely.

Comment: The problem is not with running the renewal script but with fetching the user's certificates. (Yes, it was a double hop issue and it was solved with credssp)
When a user logs in to a server manually for the first time, the certificates are automatically downloaded. Whereas, when I start a remote session through Powershell for the first time, no certificates appear in mmc.

Comment: are you trying to fetch certificates in the **User** Cert Store for a *different* user, or your own user account?

Comment: I am trying to fetch certificates in the CurrentUser directory for the the same user whose credentials I'm using to login during Enter-PSSession